# PHP MySQL compatible with Play Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, playframework

I have a working project with Wamp Server and MySQL database. All the queries are done using PHP inside a html document set to be treated as php. However, I wonder if this project could be integrated into a Play Framework environment, as it is more "Java-friendly". I know I can configure a MySQL5 database on play but, would the same system as I have configurated work?

Comment: This sounds rather odd to me... Do you want play to run a php script which then will execute some sql queries on your db? What do you mean by "Java-friendly"?

Comment: Clarify better what do you want to achieve

Comment: I mean, now I have a set of html files that load the data from different databases and plot them in Real time using Flot Charts. I wonder if this is possible just from a Play Framework environment, in which the html files are stored in the app/views folder. I meant Java-friendly because the way of rendering, obtaining the different elements, etc. is done in the examples with Java, not entirely in Javascript + PHP (all the queries, events, ...) inside a html file.

Comment: This is actually what a web framework such as play is made for. So it's totally possible. But before starting I recommend to familiarize yourself with the "Model-View-Controller" pattern (play is an MVC framework).  Putting everything in view files is considered bad practice.

Comment: That's what I meant, exactly. I'm still familiarizing with the MVC Framework that is a bit difficult to understand at first (I'm still learning the very basics of Java). I know it's bad practice, but would a html file inside Views calling the BD with PHP and Javascript work? It's just to test it.

Comment: Nope, that's not possible. It would be useless anyway. You couldn't use any of play's features.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do adapt it to the MVC format. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL-Server from Wamp, with your current database and all the tables, etc. Just be careful with the database-evolutions in play, you probably need to disable those.

But besides that, you should be able to use play with your current MySQL configuration, and you should be able to access your MySQL server from both play and your php-application at the same time.